# x-axis labels are not showing at some plots (stacked bar plot)

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis-labels

I am designing a sheet with multiple plots, but for all the bar plots with only one bar the x-axis label isn't shown. 
How can I make the axis label be shown at all my plots?

Here is my result:

[image: The result I get]

Here is my code:

```
library(utils)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
rm(list=ls())

color <- brewer.pal(6,"Spectral")
overlap <- read_excel("overlap.xlsx")
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1),mgp=c(2,0.9,0),xaxs="i", yaxs="i")


overlap.dat <- overlap[overlap$`Countries and areas`=="Pakistan",]
overlap.dat <- t(overlap.dat)
colnames(overlap.dat) = overlap.dat[5,]
overlap.dat <- as.matrix(overlap.dat[-c(1:8,14),])

barplot(overlap.dat, main = "Pakistan", col = color, ylim = c(0,100), xlim = c(0, 8),
        cex.names = 0.8, names.arg = colnames(overlap.dat), legend = TRUE, 
        args.legend = list(x = "topright", y = 100, cex = 0.8, bty = "n"), las = 2 )
```

Comment: Please provide some data (e.g. using `dput(overlap.dat)`) so we can run your code.

Comment: https://data.unicef.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/UNICEF_Global_Databases_Stunting_Wasting_Overweight_2018_May.xlsx This is were I got the data from :)

Comment: But I have solved it already. The problem was that r changed my matrix to a vector for all the single row dataframes.

Comment: If you want help it is advised to make it easy as possible for others to help you, that means if we can reproduce your problem by simply copying and pasting some code from your question we are more inclined to do so than if we need to download and import some data.

Comment: Thanks I will look into the dput function as I have never used it before. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

But I have solved it already. The problem was that r changed my matrix to a vector for all the single row dataframes.

Here the code how I solved it:

```
color <- brewer.pal(6,"Spectral")
overlap <- read_excel("overlap.xlsx")
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1),mgp=c(2,0.9,0),xaxs="i", yaxs="i")

overlap.dat <- overlap[overlap$`Countries and areas`=="Pakistan",]
overlap.dat <-as.data.frame(t(overlap.dat))
overlap.dat <- as.matrix(overlap.dat, drop=FALSE)
overlap.dat <- as.matrix(overlap.dat[-c(1:8,14),], drop=FALSE)
colnames(overlap.dat)= overlap[overlap$`Countries and areas`=="Pakistan",]$Year

barplot(overlap.dat, main = "Pakistan", col =color,  ylim=c(0,100), xlim=c(0,8),cex.names=0.8, names.arg = colnames(overlap.dat),
        legend=TRUE, args.legend = list(x="topright",y=100, cex=0.8,bty="n"), las=2 )
```